# Map Ansible return values to a second task

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm trying to take the output of one Ansible task, map the objects within, then pass it to a second task:

```
- name: Get tables
  postgresql_query:
    db: "{{ db_name }}"
    login_host: "{{ login_host }}"
    login_user: "{{ login_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ login_password }}"
    query: SELECT * FROM pg_tables t WHERE t.tableowner = current_user
  register: tables
```

Which outputs:

```
"tables": {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "query": "SELECT * FROM pg_tables t WHERE t.tableowner = current_user", 
    "query_result": [
        {
            "hasindexes": true, 
            "hasrules": false, 
            "hastriggers": true, 
            "rowsecurity": false, 
            "schemaname": "public", 
            "tablename": "my_table2", 
            "tableowner": "my_user", 
            "tablespace": null
        },
        {
            "hasindexes": true, 
            "hasrules": false, 
            "hastriggers": true, 
            "rowsecurity": false, 
            "schemaname": "public", 
            "tablename": "my_table", 
            "tableowner": "my_user", 
            "tablespace": null
        }
    ]
```

I'd like to take this make it just a list of `tablename`s to pass to a second task.

I thought I could do the following:

`"{{ tables.query_result | map(attribute='tablename') | list }}"`

but this gives me an undefined variable error.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_query

```
"{{ tables.query_result|json_query('[*].tablename') }}"
```

Comment: I actually want the tablenames of the entire list.  Sorry my example only had a single list element, I updated it to be more clear.

Comment: Use json_query.